# Capistrano/Rails not showing latest change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I am using `rails 4` with `nginx` and `passenger` for my personal project. Today I decided to use `capistrano` for deployment. My capsitrano config is working fine and I am able to deploy my application to production. After deploying I can see my changes in `current` folder and latest `release` folder. But I don't see the changes in browser.

let's say I have following folder structures on my server after setting up capistrano.

```
[1]app_name/app/views/finance/index.html
[2]app_name/releases/<latest_release>app/views/finance/index.html
[3]app_name/current/app/views/finance/index.html
```

If I ssh into server then `I can see my code changes are applied to folder structure [2] and [3]` but my code in not updated in folder structure [1].

Below are snippets from my cap files:

`production.rb`

```
set :port, 22
set :user, 'deploy'
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false

server 'xx.xxx.x.xxx',
  roles: [:web, :app, :db],
  port: fetch(:port),
  user: fetch(:user),
  primary: true

set :deploy_to, "/var/www/app_name"

set :ssh_options, {
  forward_agent: true,
  auth_methods: %w(publickey),
  user: 'deploy',
}

set :rails_env, :production
set :conditionally_migrate, true
```

`deploy.rb`

```
lock '3.4.0'

set :application, 'app_name'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:user_name/app_name.git'

# Default branch is :master
set :branch, 'master'

set :use_sudo, false
set :bundle_binstubs, nil

# Default value for :scm is :git
set :scm, :git

# Default value for :format is :pretty
set :format, :pretty

# Default value for :log_level is :debug
set :log_level, :debug

# Default value for :pty is false
set :pty, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml')

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system')


# Default value for keep_releases is 5
set :keep_releases, 5
set :keep_assets, 3

namespace :deploy do
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app) do
      within release_path do
        execute :touch, 'tmp/restart.txt'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Do I need to point my application server to `current` directory?

Comment: app_name/app is not a location that Capistrano places the repository. Perhaps you manually put the code there? You should probably be using app_name/app/current.

Comment: @ollpu yes I put code under app_name/app location. It was there before capistrona was set. Now I have setup capistrona which pushes code to current directory. How can i use app_name/app/current ?. Can i tell passenger to point to current directory some how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by telling `nginx` to point to `current/public` folder.

```
root /var/www/app_name/current/public;
```